# Api endpoint is present on test environment but not available on production, what http status code and message will be suitable for it?

Tags: api, http, production-environment, production, test-environments

The api endpoint is present on test environments but not available on production. What should happen if consumer calls the same api in production environment?

Currently I use `404 - Not found`, Which is a bit misleading for consumer, Consumer might think that we removed support of api-endpoint from every environments.

Can you suggest some better solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

404 is really the best response when an item is missing.  However, there are places where the status text of "Not Found" can be replaced with something like "Not in Production".